# Maximum edges in degree-restricted digraph

Tags: graphs

How many edges can there be in a loop-free, asymmetric $n$-vertex digraph, if each node can have maximum total degree $k$ and minimum total degree $m$?

That is,

1. There are no edges $(v,v)$ (self-loops),
2. if there is an edge $(u,v)$, there is no edge $(v,u)$,
3. $d_{\mathrm{in}}(v) + d_{\mathrm{out}}(v)\leq k$ for every vertex $v$, and
4. $d_{\mathrm{in}}(v) + d_{\mathrm{out}} \geq m$ for every vertex $v$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a directed graph on $n$ vertices has total degree $k$ then it has at most $nk/2$ edges. If the out-degree is at least $m$ then it has at least $nm$ edges. So we must have $m \leq k/2$. So your example has *no* solution.

Comment: Then the answer is 44, using the construction in my answer (with different parameters).

Comment: For Example:  I have a digraph with 22 vertex, where each vertex has maximum 4 and minimum 3 total degree.  SparseAdjmatrix = {(9, 1), (21, 1), (6, 2), (21, 2), (1, 3), (7, 3), (10, 4), (11, 4), (8, 5), (15, 5), (8, 6), (15, 6), (2, 7), (4, 7), (3, 8), (7, 9), (20, 9), (2, 10), (22, 10), (14, 11), (17, 11), (14, 12), (22, 12), (1, 13), (20, 13), (5, 14), (13, 14), (16, 15), (10, 16), (11, 16), (12, 17), (19, 17), (12, 18), (13, 18), (18, 19), (4, 20), (19, 20), (3, 21), (5, 21), (16, 22), (18, 22)}  Total Edge in the example is 41

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience @YuvalFilmus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has changed and will probably change again in the future. It wasn't clear to start with, so the question I was trying to answer is:

> How many edges can a directed graph on 22 vertices have, if the out-degree is at most 4, and the in-degree is at least 3?

Connect each node $x$ to nodes $x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4$, all indices taken modulo $22$. This satisfies all your conditions and has 88 edges, which is also trivially the maximum.

Comment: I think the case $m=4$ was intended to be an example, not the whole question.

Comment: Well, the example generalizes.

Comment: There's also an unclear maximum degree condition: "each node is allowed to have maximum k connections." (I can't tell if that's supposed to mean in-degree, out-degree or total degree.) That means there will be no solutions for some values of the parameters.

Comment: I am talking about total degree (in-degree + out-degree)

Comment: Can you please explain why you are taking modulo 22 of all indices

Comment: Unfortunately, now that the question has been clarified, this graph violates the degree condition: each vertex has total degree 8.

Comment: @David The current formulation doesn't make sense, since a graph with total degree 4 and 22 vertices can have at most 44 edges, rather than at least 82 as claimed. The same construction gives the optimal 44 edges for the current formulation of the question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Argh, you're right. The whole thing's a mess. I shouldn't have retracted my close vote.